# Issues trying to deploy rails app with capistrano using run cap deploy:cold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, svn, capistrano

I'm working on deploying a rails app via capistrano, and I'm getting an error on svn checkout.

Here's the error that I'm getting:

```
failed: "sh -c 'svn checkout -q --username Username --password Password 
--no-auth-cache  -r108 https://subdomain.svn.beanstalkapp.com/main/trunk/project
/var/www/vhosts/example.com/releases/20120807043050 && (echo 108 > 
/var/www/vhosts/example.com/releases/20120807043050/REVISION)'" on example.com
```

I'm not sure what is causing this error. How can I troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that subversion was not installed on my server. To install subversion on centos via yum:

```
uname -a
```

If the result contains `i686` your server is 32-bit, if it contains `x86_64`, it is 64-bit. Now check yum for the latest version of svn:

```
yum list available | grep subversion
```

find the apprioriate version (32 or 64 bit) and then do:

```
yum install subversion.<appropriate version>
```